# Ryzen 5900HX + RTX3070 – black screen on boot when external screen plugged in after update to 21.10

Tags: nvidia, external-monitor, 21.10

I have recently upgraded my laptop to Ubuntu 21.10. I have Ryzen 5900HX and GeForce RTX 3070 onboard. Unfortunatelty I can turn on the computer only without the external screen plugged to an HDMI port (plugging it in after boot does not work either, but this never worked with this laptop).

When the external screen is plugged in, it won't even make it to the login screen – the computer freezes, screen is all black and I cannot do anything (including chainging TTY, so that I cannot see any error message as well).

Nvidia driver is installed and it seems to work (including Wayland) unless an external screen is plugged in.

What can I do or even where can I find logs to see where the problem is?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html.en

Comment: In case anyone else has the problem, current situation seems to look like this:
- after upgrading to Ubuntu 21.10 Wayland still won't work with NVidia. You need to install the libnvidia-egl-wayland1 package on your own, then it will start working.
- Ryzen 5000's GPU will not work with HDMI output.
- Prime seems not to work as well, so when the laptop is in hybrid mode set in UEFI, Nvidia won't kick in
- Switching to dGPU only mode in UEFI makes both NVidia/Wayland and HDMI work properly (but still requires the HDMI to be plugged in before turning on the computer).

Comment: Sounds like you might want to answer your own question. Comments can go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has the problem, current situation seems to look like this:

- after upgrading to Ubuntu 21.10 Wayland still won't work with NVidia. You need to install the `libnvidia-egl-wayland1` package on your own, then it will start working.
- Ryzen 5000's GPU will not work with HDMI output.
- Prime seems not to work as well, so when the laptop is in hybrid mode set in UEFI, Nvidia won't kick in
- Switching to dGPU only mode in UEFI makes both NVidia/Wayland and HDMI work properly (but still requires the HDMI to be plugged in before turning on the computer).